# which action to hook to in order to perform post-publish action

Tags: posts, plugin-development, php, admin

I have some functionality I've written in order to post the title and link for the post to twitter whenever a post is published.

I'm wondering which wp function to hook this to? [save_post has no real reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/save_post) documentation. Basically I just want to run an action when a post is successfully published.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hook into `publish_post` like the plugin [Inform about Content](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/inform-about-content/) does.

But this hook is fired on updates to published posts too, this may result in many redundant tweets …

Try `'draft_to_publish'` instead. It is called in `wp_transition_post_status()` and happens only one time. You get the `$post` object as argument.

Prototype, not tested:

```
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'wpse_55516_tweet_new_post' );

function wpse_55516_tweet_new_post( $post )
{
    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type )
    {
        return;
    }

    // Tweet it like a boss …
}
```

Comment: Nice!!!... that looks like the one. Yeah that was something I overlooked: how annoying it would be for followers to get get the tweet every typo change.. I'll give it a try now..

Comment: that's the one!!