# Sends out email to admin

Tags: posts, admin, email

Are there any plugin or code  that sends out a email to me (admin) when a author or writer publish a post?

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/55516/73.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for plugin here are a few lines of code you can modify and paste in your themes functions.php file and you will get a new email whenever a post is published:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'send_admin_email');
function send_admin_email($post_id){
    $to = 'admin@email.here';
    $subject = 'mail subject here';
    $message = "your message here ex: new post published at: ".get_permalink($post_id);
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message );
}
```

Comment: bainternet thank you it works perfect. but how can i add the subject and body field to email?

Comment: and also if possible  category field

Comment: hmmmm, the answer shows how to set both subject and body of the mail (message = body, in email)

Comment: what i try to say is: i want to add title of the post and body of the post, and category in to email.

Comment: ok then, for the title use: `get_the_title($post_id);` and for the categories use `$categories = get_the_category($post_id); implode(" ,",$categories);`

Comment: `$message = "your message here ex: new post published at: ".get_permalink($post_id); get_the_title($post_id); get_the_category($post_id);` i put this code but it isnt working. am i doing something wrong? and how am i going to add body in to mail? i am not good with php. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/email-alerts/ this is good for a single or multisite set up where each user wants different email alert settings. Activate the plugin and then go to the user's profile to update the alert settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for this:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/email-post-changes/

After install go to **Settings** of the plugin (the settings link in the plugin list).

Enter your Email Adress and make sure to enable "**Drafts**" at the bottom - this will also send you notifications on **new posts**.